# Adding second mmcblk device

Tags: qemu

I have a arm vexpress-a9 built from buildroot with rootfs on mmcblk0 with command line:

```
exec qemu-system-arm -M vexpress-a9 -smp 1 -m 256 -kernel zImage -dtb vexpress-v2p-ca9.dtb -drive file=rootfs.ext4,if=sd,format=raw -append "console=ttyAMA0,115200 rootwait root=/dev/mmcblk0"  -net nic,model=lan9118 -net user  ${EXTRA_ARGS}
```

I need to add another mmcblk device with 7 partitions.
I created a raw image file and created 7 partitions with disk.
But trying to run:

```
exec qemu-system-arm -M vexpress-a9 -smp 1 -m 256 -kernel zImage -dtb vexpress-v2p-ca9.dtb -drive file=rootfs.ext4,if=sd,format=raw -drive file=disk2.img,if=sd,format=raw  -append "console=ttyAMA0,115200  rootwait root=/dev/mmcblk0"  -net nic,model=lan9118 -net user  ${EXTRA_ARGS}
```

"machine type does not support if=sd,bus=0,unit=1"
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The vexpress-a9 machine has only one SD controller, so you can't use more than one SD card. (This is the emulated-machine equivalent to the real world scenario where the board has only one SD card slot -- you physically can't put more than one SD card in at once.)